# PrimeFaces update single row of datatable from dialogue

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a requirement where I am using rowExpension inside a datatable. 
which opens another datatable(sub table). 
Below sub table I have one edit button.
upon clicking edit it opens model dialogue and once I click save it closes the dialogue but I am not able to find a way to update that particular sub table.

Below is the code snippet of subtable & dialogue. Can anybody suggest me a way to update the particular subtable for which the edit button is clicked.

```
<p:rowExpansion id="partyRows">
                                <p:dataTable 
                                    var="party" 
                                    value="#{pocAccountBean.parties}" 
                                    rows="20"
                                    id="test"
                                    widgetVar="partyTable"
                                    resizableColumns="true" 
                                    emptyMessage="No associated parties found." 
                                    rowIndexVar="idx"
                                    styleClass="testClass_#{account.accountNbr}">

                                    <p:column headerText="Party Name" sortBy="#{party.partyKey}">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{party.partyKey}" />
                                    </p:column>

                                    <p:column headerText="Party Type" sortBy="#{party.partyType}">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{party.partyType}" />
                                    </p:column>

                                    <p:column headerText="Agent Code" sortBy="#{party.agentCode}">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{party.agentCode}"/>
                                    </p:column>

                                    <p:column headerText="Party Status" sortBy="#{party.partyStatus}">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{party.partyStatus}" />
                                    </p:column>

                                    <p:column headerText="Education Level" sortBy="#{party.educationLevel}">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{party.educationLevel}" />
                                    </p:column>

                                    <p:column headerText="Current Date" sortBy="#{party.currentDate}">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{party.currentDate}" />
                                    </p:column>

                            </p:dataTable>

                            <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5" border="0">
                                 <p:commandButton value="Edit" type="button" onclick="PF('dlg2').show();"/>
                            </h:panelGrid>

                            <p:dialog header="Terms" widgetVar="dlg2" modal="true" height="400" width="800" id="d1" dynamic="true">
                                <h:inputText value="#{pocAccountBean.agentCode}" />
                                <p:commandButton action="#{pocAccountBean.setAgentCodeInParties()}" value="Save" onclick="PF('dlg2').hide();" update="@(.testClass_#{account.accountNbr})"></p:commandButton>
                            </p:dialog>

                        </p:rowExpansion>
```

Comment: I tried using css selector in update attribute, but seems like in primefaces dynamic value of update attribute is not supported.

Comment: a workaround would be to use c:foreach where you can give dynamic ids. So you can user the id to update. You cant use the css selector to update.

Comment: Please state your PF Version? (always do, as well as JSF impl and version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("form:something:" + index + "something");
```

This is what worked for me.
"update" attribute does not take run time expression value.

Answer (score 0):

To update a specific row in datatable you can use RequestContext to update specific component, so remove the update expression from your commandButton, and add this to your setAgentCodeInParties method:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(
  s.getClientId(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()) 
  + ":" + event.getRowIndex() 
  + ":***"
);
```