# How to update one single row in p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a dataTable in my page, and I need update in single row after any event. For example, one click in button. Please any tips?
I would like to do this using only the features of Primefaces and jsf is this possible?

```
 <h:form id="formDtable" prependId="false">
      <p:dataTable id="surveyDt"
                   value="#{surveyCtr.veicLazyDataModel}"
                   var="veiculos"
                   scrollRows="100"
                   scrollable="true"
                   liveScroll="true"
                   scrollHeight="430"
                   emptyMessage=""
                   rowKey="#{veiculos.seqID}"
                   rowIndexVar="row"
                   lazy="true" 
                   style="font-size: 10px;" >

          <f:facet name="header">
            <p:outputLabel value="Teste Lazy BD" class="fontTituloTabela"/>
          </f:facet>
          <p:column headerText="Vehicle ID" >
            <h:outputText value="#{veiculos.vehicleID}" />
          </p:column>
          <p:column headerText="Vehicle Type Code" >
            <h:outputText value="#{veiculos.vehicleTypeCode}" />
          </p:column>
          <p:column headerText="Code" >
            <h:outputText value="#{veiculos.fltCode}" />
          </p:column>
          <p:column headerText="Branch Code" >
            <h:outputText value="#{veiculos.branchCode}" />
          </p:column>
          <p:column headerText="Air Steer" >
            <h:outputText value="#{veiculos.AirSteer}" />
          </p:column>
          <p:column headerText="Rec Air Drive" >
            <h:outputText value="#{veiculos.AirDrive}" />
          </p:column>
          <p:column headerText="Rec Air Free" >
            <h:outputText value="#{veiculos.AirFree}" />
          </p:column>
          <p:column headerText="Rec Air Spare" >
            <h:outputText value="#{veiculos.AirSpare}" />
          </p:column>
          <p:column headerText="Qtde Spare" >
            <h:outputText value="#{veiculos.qtdSpares}" />
          </p:column>
          <p:column headerText="tipo de Controle" >
            <h:outputText value="#{veiculos.vehicleMType}" />
          </p:column>

          <p:column headerText="Update" >
            <p:commandButton id="btnupdatet" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil" 
                             update="formDtable:**row(index 0 ????)**">     
            </p:commandButton>
          </p:column>
```

Comment: Please post some code and more details about your problem.

Comment: @JMSilla thanks, i updated my question, please any tips?

Comment: There are duplicates of this question in stackoverflow!

Comment: Hi please @Kukeltje , you can send me the link of the question ?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=update+single+row+in+datatable+primefaces+stackoverflow

Comment: @Kukeltje if I asked the question here , of course I had exhausted my Google searches . Thank you anyways

Comment: Read the first couple of sentences here [ask]... If you searched, found similar questions that helped why did you not state so? If you searched and found nothing, maybe my search statement helps. If not, why not? Why is your question different than the others?

Comment: @Kukeltje my question is specific for dataTable, i want update in single row, or better in a specific line after any event. For exemple, one click in one button. Without using other libraries as ominifaces. Thanks friend for your time i solved my problem, will update my question

Comment: first hit (for me): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35861383/primefaces-update-single-row-of-datatable-from-dialogue did it help? Second hit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257554/how-to-update-specific-row-in-primefaces-datatable, third hit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30120998/update-single-row-from-datatable-jsf-ajax

Comment: @Kukeltje thanks for reply and help. :)

Comment: you are welcome, I think... But why not respond? Did you find or not find those links? Did they help or not, if not, why not...

Comment: @Kukeltje 
Yes, of course it helped. It was one of the questions I've seen on the omnifaces and managed to make it work on my project . But I also saw that it is possible to do without the library , in this case have not tested , but I would do it as soon as possible . thank you again